# no shutdown, no boot after latest SW update Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, kubuntu, shutdown

04 on a intel nuc with i3-8109U CPU.
A few days ago, after installing latest update the system did not shut down anymore. After hard shutdown I was not able to boot anymore. Today I have re-installed from a USB-Stick and everything (shutdown/boot) ok. After installing the updates the same error occures.
What can I do? 
Hans

Comment: Can you shut your computer down with command line - sudo poweroff ?

Comment: @FloT It is recommended to use the `sudo systemctl poweroff` command instead.

Comment: It IS possible to shut down with shutdown command (only once). But not to 'boot' anymore afterwards. I should be more precise: It is booting (Kubuntu logo appears) but then the screen is remains black. I believe it is something with graphics driver that's why I explicetly mentioned the CPU architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the failure has been fixed with a later update release. I've been waiting four weeks without touching the version (only security update for firefox installed). Then I simply tried again to install all 285 updates. Everything still works ok after.